# A complete page is compiled in Network(developer tools of chrome) When I refresh a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, laravel

When I fresh A specific on the page. It complied or loaded the complete page in the **Network**(developer tools in chrome). What I want Is that I only want to compile the specific div which I want to refresh in the **Network**(developer tools in chrome).
**Script Code**

```js
// refresh event div after 5 sec
let interOut = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('change.event') }}",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.data) {
                if (!(response.data.id == $('#event_id').val())) {
                    $('#event-refresh').load(location.href + ' #event-refresh');
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                        timeReset();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            } else if (response.data == null) {
                $('#event-refresh').load(' #event-refresh');
            }
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

**Blade Code**

```xml
<div class="card-body" id="event-refresh">
  <div  class="list-group mt-2">
    @if (!$display)
      <h2 class="font-weight-bold mt-5" id="Nothing">Currently No Event Is Active</h2>
    @else
      <h3 class="font-weight-bold p-2 text-light text-center bg-primary" id="eventTitle">{{ $display->title }}</h3>
      <p class="text-justify" id="EventDesc">{{ $display->description }}</p>
      {{-- Displaying questions of Active event from database --}}
      @if (count($display->EventQues) != 0)
        @foreach ($display->EventQues as $data)
          <input type="hidden" id="event_id" value="{{ $display->id }}">
          <div id="quesDiv1">
            <h4 class="text-center p-2">Time :<span id="timer"> </span></h4>
            <input type="hidden" id="q_time" value="{{ $display->timer }}">
            <h5 id="question">{{ $data->question }}</h5>
            <form id="form-id">
              @csrf
              <input type="hidden" id="questionId" value="{{ $data->id }}">
              <div class="btn btn-group-toggle d-flex flex-column" id="radioDiv" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option_a1" class="answer-check-box" data-value="1"> Yes
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option_a2" class="answer-check-box" checked data-value="2"> NO
                </label>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        @endforeach
      @else
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold mt-5" id="Nothing">Currently No Questions for this Event</h2>
      @endif
    @endif
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well that's what `.load(location.href + ' #event-refresh')` _does_ - it requests the document returned for the given URL (here the current one, but it could be any other), and then it extracts only the contents of `#event-refresh` from that whole document. If you do not want that - then you need to make your server-side code return only the _relevant_ part to begin with. But then you probably also need something, that makes this request distinguishable from a "normal" one for that page.

Comment: A bit unrelated, but you have a lot of `id` attributes inside a foreach. That is going to cause duplicate ids. A quick way to solve this is by using the special `$loop` variable. For example `id="event_id_{{ $loop->index }}"`

Comment: @IGP thanks for your suggestion i will surely do this

Comment: @CBroe Yes I was using the same **.load(location.href + id)** but in the network, it renders all the complete page.

Comment: Yes, and as I said, _that's just how it works_. If you want any different behavior - then you need to create some sort of endpoint in your server-side script, that returns only the desired content to begin with.

Comment: you can use `@isset($display->EventQues)` instead of   `@if (count($display->EventQues) != 0)` or you can use     `@forelse ($display->EventQues as $data ) @empty  @endforelse`